# Insert ignore into table statement in rails active records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How can i use an `active record` method in rails to ignore the errors while inserting a duplicate entry. My database already has unique specified in it.

Answer (score 1):

With Rails >= 3, you can use this:

```
    begin
      Device.create!(attributes)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
      # The device already exists.
    end
```

It's important that you use the create! (with trailing bang char). This raises an exception if the record can't be saved for whatever reason, in this case we are aiming to rescue `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`.

I recommend you to put this on a model method with a descriptive name, like `create_if_not_exists`.